# Magento - custom form

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a form, which at the moment is a simple HTML based one, that doesn't do anything.

What I'm looking to do though, is to be able to send an email once the form has been submitted and also save the data to the database.

The problem comes, with the email sending. In the form, there is a drop down menu. The menu items are items in my suppliers model/module, which have a name and email address.

So, when I select Supplier A, the form passes validation, it needs to send Supplier A an email and save the details (this shouldn't be too hard).

I'm just not sure how I'd get the email address.

Would I need to pass some kind of parameter to a custom sendEmail() method?

All help appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Ok, so before I do the email part, I'd like to store the data in the table, named test drive.

I've created the module in the admin and a form to submit data from on the frontend end.

But I cannot seem to get the data to insert.

All help is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending email see this `Mage_Contacts_IndexController::postAction()` action or
`Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()`

If You created module with model, you can get instance of that model, insert data and then save it or You can create `ResourceModel` and then execute SQL.

Comment: I have the module created in my admin and can save data in the admin backend. I just need to hook up a form on the frontend, to this module/model. any ideas?

Comment: @terrid25 Don't know what You mean by "hook up"...
Please explain in steps what do You want to accomplish.